# How to tell if a Big Query table is actually clustering the data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables that are partitioned and clustered. In one (the smaller one) the clustering is definitely helping the queries. On the larger one, it is doing nothing. Now, I only recently added clustering. I did this by creating a blank table from the schema of an existing table. I partitioned it on a DATE, and added a single clustered column that is TEXT. I then used INPUT INTO from the old table all the rows from the original table - with the hopes that it would cluster the data as if it was all new to the table. However, there is no improvement in the queries like my other table.

What I am wondering is, is there a way to see if the data is actually clustered? I see from a console command the schema has the proper column marked as a cluster column. Does the clustering not happen immediately? Just trying to verify that the data is clustered in the table or not. If not, that explains why the queries are not improved. If it is, then I don't understand why there is no improvement. Daily we add on average at least 2 million records to the table.

Querying table without clustering and one with clustering. Queries are about the same. I have searched several places to find this answer...noting specifically for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How many distinct values are in the clustered column? The more distinct values are in the column the more noticeable the effect of clustering will be.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that is good to know. There are currently between 5 and 10 distinct values in the cluster column.  It's Firebase event data. The Partition is on the event date, the cluster is on the event name. This is data pulled from the actual Firebase data into our own warehouse so we can structure things the way we want and completely remove duplicates the Firebase is often riddled with. We don't pull every event into the warehouse since many Firebase generated events are not important.

Comment: The effect will also be more noticeable when filtering by values that have less records. E.e. if you have 10 records with "name1" and 1000000 records with "name2" then `when event = "name1"` will be much faster vs `when event = "name2"`.